# Change color of graphic rectangle dynamically

Tags: c#, graphics, drawrectangle

I have write a c# class, which contains graphics inside.
this is how I build the class and draw the rectangle. It works perfectly:

```
public Graphics shape;
public Rectangle rc;

// constructor
public CLASS_NAME(Graphics formGraphics)
{
    this.shape = formGraphics;
}

public void draw(int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
    SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
    this.rc = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
    this.shape.FillRectangle(myBrush, rc);

    myBrush.Dispose();
}
```

then I wanted to add a new method to the object in order to change the color, but when I call this nothing happens:

```
public void change_color()
{
    SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow);
    this.shapeFillRectangle(myBrush, rc);
    myBrush.Dispose();
}
```

I also tried: `rc.Fill =` but VS doesn't recognize `rc.Fill` as a valid method.

- **THE ERROR I GET IS**: it says that in the `change()` method, this line: `this.shapeFillRectangle(myBrush, rc);` has a parameter that isn't valid.

Comment: Are you calling your `draw(x,y,w,h)` method before you call `change_color`? If not try doing that.

Comment: @CarbineCoder yes, first I draw it and onlt after I call the change method

Comment: In that case, I dont know the root cause, but my guess is shape.FillRectange doesnt work when you call it the second time. It would be useful if you can show how you are using the object of the class- CLASS_NAME

Comment: @CarbineCoder you are right! I did `Disposed()` on the formGraphics that I sent to the class, and it closed it for editing, then after I called the `change()` method. but that leads to another problem - when should I do `Dispose` on the `formGraphics`? I want to be able to edit the graphics the whole time the program is on.

Comment: You can try implementing IDisposable pattern for CLASS_NAME and dispose my brush in the dispose method

Comment: @CarbineCoder the issue withn't with disposing the brush, but with disposing the formGraphics. I am creating several rectangles objects with this formGraphics with a loop, then I dispose this formGraphics after the loop, and I call the change() method after I dispose the formGraphics. but I don't want to dispose the formGraphics because I want the user to be able to change the colors the whole time. any ideas?

Comment: Is it `this.shapeFillRectangle(myBrush, rc);` or `this.shape.FillRectangle(myBrush, rc);`. Maybe you are missing a fullstop(`.`) symbol.

Comment: Then as you said, test your code without disposing the formGraphics for now. If that is the case, use IDisposable pattern for formGraphics class

Comment: Or try `using(){ ...}` because the object should not be accessible after its disposed. You can manage these casses only by using either - using or IDispose pattern. Dont call dispose outside of these.

Comment: We don't see enough code but from what I see your handling of __Graphics is probably totally wrong__.Never use `control.CreateGraphics`! Never try to cache a `Graphics` object! Either draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` or in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter..

Comment: Please note: The `Graphics` object does not __contain__ any graphics; it is a **tool** that lets you draw onto a related bitmap, including a control's surface.  The system needs to draw all the controls' surfaces at times you can't control; therefore all you want to add to those surfaces must be created from the one event that the system will call, which is the `Paint` event. Only __non-persistent__ graphics operation like displaying a dynamic rubber-band rectangle are ok with a `Graphics` object you get from `control.CreateGraphics()`. And measurements without drawing...

Comment: @Taw thank you, so can you please leave an answer with an example, how can I dynamiclly generate rectangles with a for loop, and then change their color if I want? because it seems like right now I am doing it wrong. it's working for me, but in a wrong way...

Comment: You will do some more explaining. where do you want the rectangles to be drawn? A fixed control, a bitmap or something you pick dynamically? How do you want to change the colors? And how are they created in the first place? By user interaction or by code only? How do plan to store the rectangles? A Rectangle is only four numbers; so having a class is a good start, but you need to know the answers to the above questions..

Comment: @TaW I want them to be drawn on my form on a static place, probably on a fixed control. I want to change their color when I click on a checkbox, and they are beeing created when a user upload a file. I plan to smake an object that will hold each rectangle, and then a list that will hold all the objects. This is pretty much what I did, just with the Graphics control.

Comment: Note that Graphics is __not__ a [Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx). (controls are visible object with an event model !)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, let's start with a 'drawRectangle' class. It has enough data to create a simple `Pen`, holds a `Rectangle` and also a reference to the `Control` it will draw on.

I have added a `ToString` override, so we can display it with all its properties in, say a `ListBox`..

**version 1**

```
public class DrawRectangle
{
    public Color color { get; set; }
    public float width { get; set; }
    public Rectangle rect { get; set; }
    public Control surface { get; set; }

    public DrawRectangle(Rectangle r, Color c, float w, Control ct)
    {
        color = c;
        width = w;
        rect = r;
        surface = ct;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return rect.ToString() + " (" + color.ToString() + 
               " - " + width.ToString("0.00") + ") on " + surface.Name;
    }
}
```

Next we need a list of those rectangles:

```
public List<DrawRectangle> rectangles = new List<DrawRectangle>();
```

Now let's add them in a loop in a button click:

```
private void buttonAddLoop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        rectangles.Add(new DrawRectangle(new Rectangle(i * 30, i * 30, 22, 22), 
                                            Color.Black, 3.5f, drawPanel1));
    drawPanel1.Invalidate();
}
```

Note how I invalidate the control I want them painted on by  `Invalidating` it! (You can use the `Form` as well, as `Form` inherits from `Control`..)

For this to work we need to code the `Paint` event of each control that needs to paint some of the rectangles; I use only a `Panel drawPanel1`:

```
private void drawPanel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DrawRectangle dr in rectangles)
    {
        if (dr.surface == sender)
        {
            using (Pen pen = new Pen(dr.color, dr.width))
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, dr.rect);
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can change any of our `DrawRectangles`, maybe in another button click:

```
private void buttonChangeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rectangles[3].color = Color.Red;
    rectangles[6].width = 7f;
    drawPanel1.Invalidate();
}
```

[image]

**Update:**

The above class was a simple start to show how to encapsulate the things a 'Rectangle' class would need; it was not meant to be perfect!

Here is one flaw it has: It doesn't really care enough about the best way to spread **responsibilities**. It put the burdon of drawing the rectangles on the controls and if you have more complex drawing code and more controls each of them would have to learn the more complex code. This is not good. Instead **the responsibility should stay with the Rectangle class**. The control should only tell them to draw themselves..

Here is an updated class that will do just that. As a more complex drawing it will be able to draw filled rectangles as well..:

**version 2**

```
public class DrawRectangle
{
    public Color color { get; set; }
    public float width { get; set; }
    public Color fillColor { get; set; }
    public Rectangle rect { get; set; }
    public Control surface { get; set; }

    public DrawRectangle(Rectangle r, Color c, float w, Color fill, Control ct  )
    {
        color = c;
        width = w;
        fillColor = fill;
        rect = r;
        surface = ct;
    }

    public DrawRectangle(Rectangle r, Color c, float w,  Control ct) 
    : this. DrawRectangle(r, c, w, Color.Empty, ct)  {}

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return rect.ToString() + " (" + color.ToString() + 
               " - " + width.ToString("0.00") + ")";
    }

    public void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
        if (fillColor != Color.Empty) 
            using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(fillColor))
                 g.FillRectangle(brush, rect);
        if (color != Color.Empty)
            using (Pen pen = new Pen(color, width)) g.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
    }
}
```

It uses a second color to determine the filling. (I didn't add the fill color the the `ToString` method.) It compares the color with the special color values `Color.Empty` to determine what should and shouldn't be drawn.

The loop to create the new rectangles may now include the fill color. If it doesn't, the old constructor will be called, which now sets the fill color to `Color.Empty`.

Here is how simple the `Paint` event gets:

```
private void drawPanel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DrawRectangle dr in rectangles)
        if (dr.surface == sender) dr.Draw(e.Graphics);
}
```

To fill some rectangle we can now write:

```
rectangles[2].fillColor = Color.Fuchsia;
```

[image]

**Aside:**

A note an **color comparison**:  It is not obvious, but while the color `Color.Empty` really is just 'transparent black' (0,0,0,0), **color comparison is special**: `NamedColors` as well as `KnownColors`, including `Color.Empty` always **compare false** to normal colors. To make a true color comparison one would have to cast to a 'normal' `Color`:

```
bool ok=Color.FromArgb(255,255,255,255) == Color.White;  // false
bool ok=Color.FromArgb(255,255,255 255) == Color.FromArgb(Color.White.ToArgb()); // true
```

Therefore the comparison in the `Draw` code is safe.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. great answer! and is there a way to make them **clickable**, or this is a whole other question?

Comment: You can code the `MouseClick` event and then search through the list: `foreach (DrawRectangle dr in rectangles) if (dr.rect.Contains(e.Location) dosomething..`

Comment: thank you.  I also was looking fr a way to fill those rectangles but couldn't find any way to do it... is it even possible to do it with pen?

Comment: No, you would have to use a SolidBrush. The most direct way is to add a field `bool filled` to the rectangle class but maybe it would be even better to add a second `Color `fillColor` instead. Then the Paint method would test which color is set and do the necessary stuff. You can try and I can expand the answer a little, later..

Comment: but how can I use dolid brush without doing it in my previous way that you said was wrong...? hank you I appreiciate your time and effort

Comment: See my updated answer. It both adds filling and moves the responsibility for drawing where it really belongs, i.e. to the rectangle class..

Comment: @carbinecoder: You may enjoy reading the updated version which is much more oop ;-)

Comment: WOW! thank you a lot for your time and explanation. seems like you have a lot of expirience. thank you. I am going to stretch the line a little bit more and ask: is it possible to detect mouse hover on it? I tried to do it with mouse move on the panel, and then run with a loop and check for a hit, but it renders the rectangles over and over and it's not smooth, because the user can see how the rectangles are beeing reloaded every time the mouse moves.

Comment: Well, the basic idea is right, search the rectanlge(s) the cursor is over in the mousemove. but then what do want to happen? As for the redraw-flicker you observe: it has two causes: one is that you seem to do something that triggers ther redraw; probably not really what you want. The other is that the surface control the rectangles are drawn on isn't double-buffered, right? Which type of control is it or is it the form?

Comment: The surface is a panel control, and I want to show an eefect that when the mouse is over, it will change the color of the rectangle, and when it's off go back to previous color. but as I said, it redraws all the rectangles because I loop over them, because when I detect a hit, I need to do: panel.Invalidate(), and then it redraws everything

Comment: Well that is easy and you probably already have it right: `foreach (DrawRectangle dr in rectangles)
                dr.fillColor = dr.rect.Contains(e.Location) ? Color.Wheat : Color.Empty;   drawPanel1.Invalidate();` - But drawing on a regular `Panel` is usually not a good idea. `Pane`l is multi-purpose; very useful to group controls, but not meant to draw on because it hide the `Double-Buffered` property you need for flicker-free drawing..

Comment: You __could__ use a `PictureBox` instead, which is double-buffered by default. It is a good choice for all sorts of graphics. It just is not very helpful when it comes to nesting other control inside it. But there is another, simple solution: use a `Panel` subclass with double buffering: `class DrawPanel : Panel    {
        public DrawPanel()  { DoubleBuffered = true;  }
    }`

Comment: To change your `Panel` to be a `DrawPanel` you can either replace it or you can edit the `form1.designer.cs` file at the __two__ spots where you `Panel` is __declared and instantiated__ as a `System.Windows.Forms.Panel` and replace this by `DrawPanel`. Now it won't flicker anymore :-)

Comment: for some reason my VS doesn't recognize a DrawPanel. I need to import something for it?

Comment: You simply __add the new class to your project__  just  like you added the DrawRectangle class!

Comment: it's not something that is generated in VS? anyway, picture box did the job! thank you, or is it not so recommended to use picture box?

Comment: If you only want to use the control for drawing PictureBox is just fine. If you want to nest other controls, like buttons, listboxes or panels in it it is not such a good choice, as it can't be done in the designer but only in code; so the layout is tedious to code. If you only want to draw on it and show images PBox is perfect.