# Make a picturebox scroll dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, graphics, picturebox

I've seen some answers here but I didn't find something that is suitable to my problem.

I have a picture box which I am drawing on it dynamiclly some rectangles (like so: [Change color of graphic rectangle dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39072532/change-color-of-graphic-rectangle-dynamically)).

Now, if the I draw a lot of rectangles, then the picture box isn't big enough, I don't see all the rects... so I need to make the picture box scrollable.

How is it possible?

Note: I don't have a Panel, just a PictureBox that I am filling dynamically through the code.

Comment: Why `PictureBox`? You can draw in any `Control`. Here you need a `ScrollableControl` derived class.

Comment: @IvanStoev Because I am also iterating through all the rectangles when the mouse is hover the pcture box and redrawing the rectangles (you can see in the url I wrote), and if I wont use a picture box I will get a filckr like bug when the mouse will hover the control.

Comment: `PictureBox` is to simplify showing an image. Again, you can draw with or w/o flicker in **any** `Control`.

Comment: Not true. He will have to subclass every control to include double-buffering. Which, of course, is no big deal. But __nesting a PBox in a AutoScrolling Panel__ will work just fine. All he needs to do is __enlarge th PBox, when necessary__.. Also: Autscrolling will only work to show nestes controls, not for showing graphics you draw, so nesting is necessary.

Comment: @TaW This sounds more like VB6-ish solution, but of course is an option :)

Comment: __a)__ No, this is the standard solution for making a `PictureBox` scollable, e.g. for displaying large images. __b)__ it is the only (reasonble) solution to make a drawing surface scollable. A `ScrollableControl` will not honor drawing outside its `ClientArea` from the `Paint` event. Also, __c)__: `PictureBox` , being double-buffered, is the control of choice for drawing, not just for displaying images.

Comment: @TaW (a) Which is weird because you don't need 2 controls (windows) in order to get something that is supported by every window  (b) All you need is to maintain `AutoScrollMinSize` and apply `AutoScrollPosition` to the `e.Graphics`. (c) Which you can get by a few lines of code `public class Canvas : Control { public Canvas() { this.DoubleBuffered = this.ResizeRedraw = true; } }`. (d) Following OOP one would also encapsulate `DrawRectangle` list, manipulation, logic and drawing in that custom control rather than using events (!) for drawing etc. Again, this is an option, but not the best.

Comment: Well, some of your points are valid, other not so much, imo. Yes, a panel subclass is cheap, and I have suggested it in a comment of the orginal question. But a PictureBox is still the better choice for drawing. Its BackgroundImage for a paper plus Image for caching some parts of the drawing are there right out of the box. As is zooming. You are right about the AutoScollMinSize although I see some tearing remaining sometimes. Could have other reasons, though. Having one extra control is not worth thinking about imo.

Comment: And, yes this is just a start at using oop, as was also clearly stated in my original answer. The details of how to best make it expandable etc however will depend on the direction the project is supposed to take. No use throwing too much at a newbie.. Thanks for your input anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place the `PictureBox` inside a `Panel`, with `AutoScroll=true`.

Then you can simply make the `PictureBox` larger as needed, maybe even right where the `DrawRectangles` are created..:

```
public DrawRectangle(Rectangle r, Color c, float w, Control ct)
{
    color = c;
    width = w;
    rect = r;
    surface = ct;

    if ((r.Right > surface.Width)  ||  (r.Bottom > surface.Height))
    {
        surface.Size = new Size(Math.Max(surface.Width, r.Right),
                                Math.Max(surface.Height, r.Bottom)) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! once again, you saved me lots of hours!

Comment: Good to hear it works for you, too. How are things progressing? – Also: If it was helpful, don't forget to accept the answer..

Comment: Regardless of our little "academic" discussion in the comments, this definitely deserves a vote up :)